# Red shift and expansion of universe

Tags: space-expansion, popular-science, redshift

We have been led to believe that in the theory of universe expansion, the farthest object is moving faster away from us than the nearest object, attributing the difference to red shift.

Question: is it possible, due to the decay of light towards red, that the farthest object appears or is measured to have higher redshift?

Comment: The ["tired light"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light) theory is almost 100 years old. Since you posted your question on the sci-fi stack exchange, let me mention that a rather bizarre alternative explanation of the red shift was proposed in [John D. McDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._MacDonald)'s 1949 sci-fi short story ["Flaw"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41397).

Comment: Science is not religion. It doesn't ask you to believe in anything. The evidence is simply that objects that are far away are experiencing a stronger redshift. One can "explain" that in many different ways, but only one matches all the other facts that we have been able to observe about the universe well enough. If you don't care about the self-consistency of explanations, then you are, indeed, entering the realm of beliefs and, eventually religion. There is nothing wrong with that, by the way, it's just not science.

Comment: @psyntific: May be it is true. Just need supporters.

Comment: Another way to phrase this question would be: Is is possible to distinguish between [cosmological redshift](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/C/Cosmological+Redshift), due to transport of light through expanding spacetime, and a "decay" of the intrinsic energy of a photon (as described by @bof)?